# getting driveletter of mounted iso over network

Tags: windows, powershell, networking, mount

I have a problem with getting driveletter of a mounted ISO over network. I have used `Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath $ISOPATH` for mounting. 
When i mounted ISO file, which was locally stored on disk D:\, i had no problem with getting the volume information via powershell: `Get-DiskImage -ImagePath $ISOPATH | Get-Volume`. This is how the script looks like:

```
Mount-DiskImage –ImagePath $ISOPATH 

$driveletter = (Get-DiskImage -ImagePath $ISOPATH | get-volume).driveletter + ":"
cd $driveletter\Nanoserver
```

Above code works fine with local ISO file.

However, when ISO file was mounted from a network share, the `Get-Volume` command no longer work. It doesn't see the newly mounted drive, despite the fact that its visible and accessible via windows explorer. 
Command `Get-DiskImage -ImagePath $ISOPATH | Get-Volume` no longer show any information, instead its showing nothing, blank result. 
The only way that i see this drive via powershell is by using `Get-PSdrive` command, however, its hard for me to get the letter in automated way with this command. 
Has anybody got solution to this problem?

I gladly provide any more information if required.
Thanks

Comment: Get-PSDrive | where {$_.DisplayRoot -eq $ISOPATH } should give you the drive letter.

Comment: Thanks David for the reply. Unfortunately it doesn't work neither ;( The result is blank :(

Answer (score 0):

Workaround (untested in production) based on comparing before (`$vl1`) and after (`$vl2`):

```
$vl1 = @(Get-Volume); 
$disk = Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "\\172.19.21.47\www\debian-8.8.0-amd64-netinst.iso" -PassThru ; 
$vl2 = @(Get-Volume); 
$dl = @( $vl2 | ? {$vl1 -notcontains $_} )[0].DriveLetter
```

- If you guarantee that no simultaneous disk mounts happen in your system.
- Possibly need Start-Sleep after mounting to make sure the drive letter assigned

Comment: FIlimonic, thanks for your reply. The problem is, after mounting disk image over network, Get-Volume command doesn't see this disk, so it won't be able to compare it. Now, is this something you also experience or it's just like that on my computer?

Comment: I have tested it on my pc. W10. Probably need to wait while disk mounts and add a loop do {try{$dl=...}catch{}} while ($dl -eq $null)